# What criteria make a former empire agent eligible for the amnesty program?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian* season 3, episode 3, a number of former empire operatives are part of the amnesty program on Coruscant. Why are these particular individuals eligible for this program while others of their kind are not?

Comment: Not having seen any further episodes, and the obvious parallels to Operation Paperclip, I suspect that usefulness, whether skills or publicity, is a major factor.

Comment: What kind of "operatives"? In Legends at least, there seemed to be a general agreement that if you were, say, a civil servant or police officer and the New Republic took over your planet, you should just keep showing up and doing your job until someone tells you otherwise.

Comment: @JRE In English, a plural subject (in this case "criteria") requires a plural verb form, "make" instead of "makes". Alternatively (changing the meaning slightly), "What *criterion* [singular] *makes* . . ."

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited amount we've seen of the program so far; the common elements seem to be that the participants are mid-to-low level in terms of rank. Soldiers. Comm officers. Civil planning engineers. Medical research scientists. Etc. (i.e. the vast majority of serving Imperial personnel.)

Whereas the likes of Moff Gideon being a wanted war criminal was supposedly bound for tribunal. After which it would probably be either execution or life in prison.

So from that we can conclude that seniority is a large part of the filtering process; the usual reasoning for this kind of thing being that the ones that gave the orders to commit atrocities bare greater responsibility than the ones that carried them out.
So anyone at or over a certain rank (I'm guessing Naval Captains/Army Colonels & their equivalents and up) are likely to be tried before the war crimes tribunal as a matter of course, while the lower ranks were likely granted a general amnesty on the condition that they go through the rehabilitation process and submit to the conditions and restrictions of the program. Members of special forces or other particularly nasty units outside of the rank & file likely get much less leniency, and most probably tried right alongside their superiors.
There's a very pragmatic reason for this since the sheer numbers involved make it impractical to try and convict everybody (and we're talking billions of people at least!) So efforts would naturally be focused on the worst and most directly responsible for war crimes. So Moffs. Governors. Grand Admirals, Ministers, members of the Ruling Council, particularly well known offenders etc. etc.

The 'Alphabet Squadron' novels gets into this a little bit more, though that takes place some years prior during the immediate aftermath of Endor and Operation Cinder, so it's seemingly far more chaotic with massive numbers of surrendered or captured Imperials kept in interment camps awaiting processing on a seemingly case-by-case basis.
There was also a short story called '[The Perfect Weapon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Perfect_Weapon)' that featured Bazine Netal, set just prior to 'The Force Awakens'. Part of the setting of the story is a retirement colony established by the New Republic specifically for ex-Stormtroopers, and is said to be one of many such sites across the Outer Rim.